# How to find or add the username of the printing user to an XPS printed with XPSDrv

Tags: printing, xps

Does anyone know if there is a **simple** way to include the username of the printing user somewhere accessible either in the XPS package or in any header in the data stream from the driver when using XPSDrv? By using a filter in the filter pipeline (even though it is not simple in my opinion)? By reading TCP/IP header values? I have googled my fingers short trying find a reasonable solution.

Comment: That really depends on how simple a solution you need, how you intend to recover the information, and whether this is something you intend to do as part of a custom xps driver or something you want to apply to all xps drivers on the system. Could you narrow it down a little?

Comment: @Jon: I have compiled an XPSDriver from WDK, though I would not say that I know how to code C++ and WIN32 especially well. The XPS will be sent to an application that I also have control over so I can either read the username in the communication with the application or extract it from the XPS file. Right now, in my application I dont know who has printed the XPSs since it is not included anywhere as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple? No, not really. Your best bet is probably to modify a filter in your XPS driver to do the following:

1. Extract the user token from the pipeline's property bag using the XPS_FP_USER_TOKEN key.
2. Get the user's SID from the token using [GetTokenInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446671%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
3. Get the username from the SID using [LookupAccountSID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379166%28VS.85%29.aspx)
4. Add the username to the print ticket. To keep things as simple as possible, I'd suggest reusing a field from the public schema, such as the JobComment ParameterInit.

This is all just a starting point. I suspect you're going to need to delve into the details of how an XPS driver works in order to make this a reliable solution.

Comment: Thank you @Jon. It gives me a good starting point and even if it not will be simple at least I don't need to investigate all parts of the driver to find out.

Answer (score 0):

You can store meta data in de the XPS (Core Properties), or you could probably use the print ticket for this purpose too.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but where do I read the username? And in what part of the driver would I create code that adds it there?